# Fake capitalization on an all-caps font with CSS?

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to fake lowercase letters on a font that has only one letter type, which is ALL CAPS?

> This is a sentence on Stack Overflow.

Looks like this when the font is applied:

> THIS IS A SENTENCE ON STACK OVERFLOW.

I want the capitals to be a slightly larger font size as in the example below. But without the additional HTML markup.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<span>T</span>HIS IS A SENTENCE ON <span>S</span>TACK <span>O</span>VERFLOW
```

Comment: Probably require a Small Caps font - http://www.1001fonts.com/small-caps-fonts.html

Comment: You can do it using JS, but it would do the same this, wrapping tags around those letters and then applying CSS.

Comment: There is no way to pass styles to random words; but you can target the first-letter of a tag; using ::first-letter selector;

Comment: css can only target the first letter or word in a sentence, other than that you will need extra html otherwise how would css know you want the first letter and then the `s` of stack and `o` of overflow?  You would have to edit the font file itself rather than use css

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to achieve this is with JavaScript (so you could keep the markup dynamic). The JS part that you'd need is this (remember to add `.small-caps` class to your text elements):

```
function smallCaps() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.small-caps')

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(e) {
    var text = e.innerHTML.toUpperCase()
    e.innerHTML = text.replace(/\b([A-Za-z0-9])/g, '<span class="caps">$1</span>')
  })
}
```

And also remember to add styles for the `.caps` class:

```
.caps {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

See it in action either in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/1ouLxxo8/1) or below:

```js
smallCaps()

// This is what you need:
function smallCaps() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.small-caps')

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(e) {
    var text = e.innerHTML.toUpperCase()
    e.innerHTML = text.replace(/\b([A-Za-z0-9])/g, '<span class="caps">$1</span>')
  })
}
```

```css
.caps {
  font-size: 1.4em; 
}
```

```html
<h1 class="small-caps">HELLO WORLD</h1>
<h2 class="small-caps">Nifty FOOBAR title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sentence case in `font-variant: small-caps`. The `titleCase()` function works perfectly with the letters wrapped in `<span>s`.

> *I want the capitals to be a slightly larger font size as in the example below. But without the additional HTML markup.*

The first 4 comments on OP are correct. I'd like to reaffirm @Pete's comment:

> *css can only target the first letter or word in a sentence, other than that you will need extra html otherwise how would css know you want the first letter and then the s of stack and o of overflow?*

Thus, you will get answers of every variety and each successful answer will have markup in some form or another. With JavaScript, you could have a range determined by a whitelist/dictionary but covering any range of proper nouns would be very limited. Capabilities of that magnitude should be possible with a language like Python, Java, C/C++, etc.

## Demo

```js
var main = document.body;
var text = main.textContent;
titleCase(text);
main.style.fontVariant = 'smallCaps';

function titleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<span>T</span>HIS IS A SENTENCE ON <span>S</span>TACK <span>O</span>VERFLOW
```